# Django reset a save variable to 0, preferably at home view

Tags: python, django, variables, save, reset

I'm creating a simple quiz (99% done), just need help with one last thing - probably trivial to intermediate/advanced programmers. I have created a save variable to save the user's current score. This is so that the user navigates from page to page and can still see their current score.

As the user navigates last template view, it gives the final score and a link to redirect to the homepage. This allows the user an opportunity to "retake the quiz". At this moment  (home page) I need help to reset the saved score variable to 0.

Please let me know how I can do this, thanks in advance!

models.py

```
    class Scorer(models.Model):
        score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        page = models.IntegerField()
        condition_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'quizzes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the first published question """
        return Question.objects.filter(id=1)


def vote(request, question_id, *args, **kwargs):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'quizzes/vote.html'
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    
    ### To create user scoring system ###
    scorer, created = Scorer.objects.get_or_create(page=1)


    try:
        selected_choice = question.answer_set.get(pk=request.POST['answer'])



        ### To save user score ###
        if selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=1):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=6):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=12):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=13):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=19):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=22):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=28):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=30):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=36):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=37):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=38):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
        elif selected_choice in Answer.objects.filter(id=40):
            scorer.score +=10
            scorer.save()
```

Comment: You want to access a variable anywhere in your templates but when you hit the homepage view, that variable resets to 0 if I understand ?

Comment: Yes that is correct @BriseBalloches. I'm already accessing the variables in my templates. Just need it to reset to 0 when i hit homepage view. As of now, the score just keeps tallying on. Doesn't make sense when someone's trying to retake a quiz.

Comment: What is the view matching the homepage ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that. I've done so now. Please see above as "IndexView" @BriseBalloches

Comment: In your Scorer model, do you have a foreign key with the quizz and user ? In your `get_queryset(self)` you then just need to retrieve it and set to 0.

Comment: I don't have a foreign key with the quiz and user in my Scorer model. How can I implement that? @BriseBalloches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the homepage view (IndexView) and it works now. Just had to create an IF statement when the user arrives to question 1. Then score wipes out and starts back at 0. See below for clarity:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'quizzes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        
        scorer, created = Scorer.objects.update_or_create(page=1)
        
        ### To reset scores to 0 ###
        if Question.objects.filter(id=1):
            scorer.score = (scorer.score - scorer.score)
            scorer.save()

        """Return the first published question """
        return Question.objects.filter(id=1)
```